# Iterating a Map<TypeA,Set<TypeB>> and convert it to a Map<TypeB,Set<TypeA>> in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iteration

I have a `Map<String>,Set<String>> followingMap`, where the keys are usernames and values are Sets of usernames that the key usernames follows.
I have to create a followersMap , where in this case, the followed users in the value Sets are now the keys and the value is a Set of followers according to the previous k.

Not sure if this is clear enough so as an example, an element in the followingMap would be: `key="john", value=Set["robert","andrew,"amanda"].`

In the followersMap it would be:

```
key="robert", value=Set["john"]
key="andrew", value=Set["john"]
key="amanda", value=Set["john"]
```

If a second element in followingMap is `key="alex",Set["amanda"]` that would add "alex" to the value Set of the "amanda" key.

My code should do the trick, however when testing, I'm getting keys where all value Set are being filled.

Take a look:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> followerGraph = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> me : followsGraph.entrySet()) {
              String key = me.getKey();
              Set<String> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<>();    
              Set<String> valueSet = me.getValue();
              for (String s : valueSet) {
                  if (followerGraph.containsKey(s)){
                      followerGraph.get(s).add(key);
                  } else {
                      tmp.add(key);
                      followerGraph.put(s, tmp);
                  }  
              }   
        }
```

So this is the print of the followsGraph:

```
{aliana=[@jake, @john, @erick], alyssa=[@john, @erick], 
bbitdiddle=[@rock-smith, @john, @erick], casus=[@daniel, @jake, @john, @erick], 
david=[@dude, @john]}
```

And this is the print of the followerGraph:

```
{@daniel=[casus], @rock-smith=[bbitdiddle], @jake=[aliana, alyssa, bbitdiddle, casus, david], @dude=[david], @john=[aliana, alyssa, bbitdiddle, casus, david], @erick=[aliana, alyssa, bbitdiddle, casus, david]}
```

As you can see, @erick shouln't have david as follower. Am I missing something?
Sorry if my code looks like a mess. I have just 6 months in Java, 4 hours learning how to iterate a map (tried the Java 8 streams but not sure how to add the if-else in there), and it's 6 am and my wife might kill me for staying up all night :S

Comment: Where does the followerGraph come from?

Comment: You are right. I didn't include that line. Its the 2nd map <String,Set<String>> that maps the followers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> followerMap = new HashMap<>();
    followingMap.forEach((name,followingSet)-> followingSet.forEach(
            follower-> followerMap.computeIfAbsent(follower, f->new HashSet<>())
                                  .add(name)));
```

`followingMap.forEach` process all the entries in the followingMap. Then the Set of each entry is being processed with `followingSet.forEach`. The elements of this set are the followers, the keys of the new map. `computeIfAbsent` is being used to put a new entry in the map if it doesn't exists, adding an empty Set in that case. Afterthat, the value is added to the Set, in that case the entry of the followerMap.

And this is the same code using `for` loops instead of `forEach`, probably more readable.

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> followerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Set<String>> followingEntry : followingMap.entrySet()) {
        for (String follower : followingEntry.getValue()) {
            followerMap.computeIfAbsent(follower, s->new HashSet<>()).add(followingEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker You are probably right, probably using `for` loops instead of `forEach` methods make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> me : followsGraph.entrySet()) {
    String key = me.getKey();
    // Set<String> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<>();     // MOVE THIS TO ...
    Set<String> valueSet = me.getValue();
    for (String s : valueSet) {
        if (followerGraph.containsKey(s)) {
            followerGraph.get(s).add(key);
        } else {
            Set<String> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<>();  // HERE
            tmp.add(key);
            followerGraph.put(s, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> newFollowsGraph = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> me : followsGraph.entrySet()) {
          String key = me.getKey();  
          Set<String> valueSet = me.getValue();
          for (String s : valueSet) {
              if (newFollowerGraph.containsKey(s)){
                  newFollowerGraph.get(s).add(key);
              } else {
                  Set<String> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                  tmp.add(key)
                  newFollowerGraph.put(s, tmp);
              }  
          }   
    }
```

The problem is, you are inserting new data in the object you are iterating over.